# How to populate a column from another column?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have two tables called `ComputerReport` and `SoftwareReport`. In the first table I have added an integer column called `SFID`. I use this column to make a link between the first and the second table. The second table also has a coumn called `SFID`, this is also the primary key of the table.

What I want is to fill the `SFID` column from table `SoftwareReport` into the `SFID` column of `ComputerReport`. In the picture below you see the two tables, but the `SFID` column in `ComputerReport` is `NULL`.

How can I fill the ID's from the `SoftwareReport` table into the `SFID` column of `ComputerReport` and should add only a program name when it's not exist.

Here is the link of the image: http://i33.tinypic.com/2usewr8.jpg

Thanks,

Jamie

Comment: Your logic is not clear at all. What is the link between the two tables, e.g. your first row in `ComputerReport` is `1, 'JAMIE-HP', 'JAMIE-HP/Jamie', '2013-04-24 14:21:09.000'`, I see no way of knowing what SFID this should be? With no common column (apart from the NULL SFID) there is no way to perform the update.

Comment: I made a link between them to use a column, like (WHERE ComputerReport.SFID = SoftwareReport.SFID). But I want the SFID from SoftwareReport into the ComputerReport SFID column. So when I saved a new list with program names it will check the names firstly. SQL will add only new program names. When the program name already exist in that list then he only takes the SFID and put it into the ComputerReport SFID. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Okay, but what should the `SFID` be for the first row in `ComputerReport` and why? Understanding this is key to creating the update statement, and the logic for adding new program names.

Comment: To make a link between a program name and a computer name. So I have 21 programs on my laptop. It's like (1 = Adobe, 2 = BitTorrent etc..) I want the ID's from that software (SFID) into the SFID of ComputerReport. (Last column) But it's null now. I don't know how to fill it with the SFID's of SoftwareReport.

Comment: You missed my question, in the screen shot you have posted **what should the SFID be for the first row in ComputerReport and why?**

Comment: That should be the ID of the program name from SoftwareReport. So like this: (1, 'JAMIE-HP', 'JAMIE-HP/Jamie', '2013-04-24 14:21:09.000', '1') and that last 1 is Adobe from SoftwareReport. I want that because I can search on a program name and all computers will show only that have Adobe :)

Comment: But why Adobe, and not bit torrent or Excel etc, what specifically is there in the first row that tells you that it should be for Adobe?

Comment: See the picture. I want this: http://i36.tinypic.com/2ly3eko.png

Comment: You need to be able to express what you want using words, sentences, paragraphs in english, not pictures.

Comment: You also need to explain further the circumstances of how each tables get populated beforehand, so that we may understand WHY you want it done that way.

Comment: Because I already explained 1000 times what I mean. That's why I added an extra picture. I can use it for later very easily. Just make a select command to search on a program name and get a whole list with computers. So I can see all computers who has installed a program name. But you already helped me! I really appreciated that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you should insert a row in `ComputerReport` with the correct `SFID` already decided, rather than update rows already inserted.

```
INSERT INTO ComputerReport
(SFID, CrComputerName, CrLastUpdatedBy) -- add other columns as neeeded 
SELECT SFID, 'JAMI-HP', 'JAMIE-HP\JAMIE'
FROM SoftwareReport
```

You could truncate the `ComputerReport` table and do the above insert, if the table does not contain anything valuable yet.

Otherwise, you need a cursor to follow each table, and set `SFID` in the second table at cursor position according to the value of `SFID` in the first table at cursor position.

In the ideal situation, you just created the rows, there are no gap in either tables, and they both contain the same number of rows, so we can simply write:

```
UPDATE ComputerReport 
SET SFID = CRID
```

But in the general case we must resort to a more complex script:

```
DECLARE @sfid, @crid

DECLARE sfcursor READONLY
FOR SELECT SFID
    FROM SoftwareReport
    WHERE SFName IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY SFID ASC;
DECLARE crcursor
FOR SELECT CRID
    FROM  ComputerReport
    -- WHERE SFID IS NULL
    ORDER BY CRID ASC
FOR UPDATE SFID;

OPEN sfcursor;
OPEN crcursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM sfcursor INTO @sfid;
FETCH NEXT FROM crcursor INTO @crid;

-- update for each rows until we reach the end of either cursor
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
     UPDATE crcursor SET SFID = @sfid;
     FETCH NEXT FROM sfcursor INTO @sfid
     FETCH NEXT FROM crcursor INTO @crid
     END

-- if there are remaining rows in sfcursor, insert new rows in ComputerReport

FETCH RELATIVE 0 FROM sfcursor INTO @sfid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ComputerReport (SFID) -- you should add the other columns here as needed
    VALUES (@sfid);
    FETCH NEXT FROM sfcursor INTO @sfid
    END

CLOSE crcursor
CLOSE sfcursor
DEALLOCATE sfcursor
DEALLOCATE crcursor
```

As indicated by in the script, you should amend the `INSERT` query for extra rows in `ComputerReport` with the needed columns and values.

Note that cursor based scripts are slow compared to regular (set based) queries.
References:

- [declaring cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms180169.aspx)
- [fetching cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not an expert in SQL. This is what I want. See --> http://i36.tinypic.com/2ly3eko.png

Comment: sure, I am not a SQL99 expert either. I suggest the `MERGE` query of another answer which does what my script tries to do, and _is what you want_.

Comment: btw this is my first tsql script, so don't be surprised if it's not idiomatic or even contain errors.

Answer (score 2):

If your logic is to just update the First computer report with the first item in the software report table, the 2nd with the 2nd, the 3rd with the 3rd and so on then this will work for you:

```
WITH CR AS
(   SELECT  CRID, Name, SFID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CRID) 
    FROM    ComputerReport
), SF AS
(   SELECT  SFID, Name, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SFID)
    FROM    SoftwareReport
)
MERGE INTO CR
USING SF
    ON sf.rn = cr.rn
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET SFID = sf.SFID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Name, SFID) VALUES (sf.Name, sf.sfID);
```

This simply updates the computer report table with the corresponding row from the software table if SFID. If there are additional rows in the software report table it will add a new row to the computerreport table so the row counts match

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04b08/2)**

Comment: Thank you :) But is that the same like I asked in this picture? http://i36.tinypic.com/2ly3eko.png It's just that. Not more. But when I do a scan on another computer or laptop and some program names are the same then he must take that SFID and put it in the ComputeReport (last column called SFID).

Comment: It is as close as I can get to what you want since the rules surrounding the update seem to be almost non existant. Without the SFID column in `ComputerReport` there is no logical way to link a `CRID` with a `SFID`. As far as I can tell there is no reason the row with `CRID = 1` should have `SFID` = 1, other than they are both the first rows in their respective tables. If you can provide an actual algorithm to perform the update then I may be able to suggest an answer that is better suited, but at the moment updating based on position in the table is the best I can offer.

Comment: If you don't want to insert new rows into `ComputerReport` then just remove the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` section of the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: GarethD, I'm using a stored procedure, but how can I insert that code into my stored procedure? Because in my sp I use "INSERT INTO". But that should be "MERGE INTO" then?

Comment: Yes, you can use `MERGE` within a stored procedure, just make sure you terminate the statement before hand with a `;` (Although really you should be terminating **every** statement with a semi-colon, reasons for doing so are mentioned on [Aaron Bertrand's blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)

Answer (score 0):

If I get this what you want to achieve correctly, you have to add CRID into SoftwareReport table and remove SFID from ComputerReport.

Then WHEN you add new software report you'll use CRID from last report...

This is valid is you want to achieve this:
Every time you run your check it creates new computer report and adds a new software to common list with connection when it happened, in other words which computer report reported new software.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand question very well. So sorry if my answer is not relevant. As I understood you want to link computers and software. For this you need many-to-many relationship. because one software can be on several computers and one computer can have many software. And to achieve that you need another table which is consist of two columns as:
**ComputerSoftware (CID, SFID)**.
For example, if computer which's id is 1 has software with the id 2 and 3 you should insert
(1, 2) and (1, 3) to to ComputerSoftware table.

Comment: Yea, I know what your saying. I also make a reference.

ALTER TABLE ComputerReport ADD FOREIGN KEY (SFID) REFERENCES SoftwareReport(SFID)

Because there are more programs than computers.

Comment: No I mean you need another table as ComputerSoftware (CID, SFID) which will bring computers and software together.

Comment: Ah I created a view for that. Is that what you mean?

Comment: no. don't you want to relate computers and software? For example, imagine that in Computers table you have computers like that [(C_ID, C_NAME)]: (1, "FirstComputer"), (2, "SecondComputer"). And you have following data in Software table [(SF_ID, SF_NAME)]: (1, "FirstProgram"), (2, "SecondProgram"). Now in your tables how can you say that FirstComputer has SecondProgram and SecondComputer has both, FirstProgram and SecondProgram?

Comment: This should be the result then Adil Mammadov,

ComputerReport TABLE:
1, "FirstComputer", "LastUpdatedBy", "LastUpdatedOn", 12
2, "FirstComputer", "LastUpdatedBy", "LastUpdatedOn", 6
3, "FirstComputer", "LastUpdatedBy", "LastUpdatedOn", 2

---------

SoftwareReport TABLE:
1, "Adobe Reader"
2, "Messenger"
...
6, "Skype"
...
12, "BitTorrent"
...

So one computer called "FirstComputer" has the next programs installed:

2 = Messenger
6 = Skype
12 = BitTorrent

This should be the results then. I hope you understand me now